# nil is the only return value permitted in initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm attempting to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout but I get the error that 'nil is the only return value permitted in an initializer.' I attempted to check the super class for an initializer and if there wasn't, I would return nil, but alas, I get another error saying that self is immutable.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewSpringLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    var dynamicAnimator: UIDynamicAnimator?
    override init() {


        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        //self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(44, 44)
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(collectionViewLayout: self)
        return self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `return self` in Swift.

Comment: oh lord, i keep confusing obj-c with swift..

Comment: In Obj-C `- (instancetype)init` is a method, and needs a return value. In Swift, initializers are special, they're not ordinary functions :)

Comment: Aside from the asked question, you're also missing `super.init()`

Answer (score 4):

As @jtbandes mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't be calling `return self`. [Swift-book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) states:

> Unlike Objective-C initializers, Swift initializers do not return a
>   value.

(This doesn't apply to [failable initialisers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224))